# Ubuntu 11.10 Dual Screen, Configuration of 1 Touchscreen Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calibrate a touchscreen on a dual monitor system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51445/how-do-i-calibrate-a-touchscreen-on-a-dual-monitor-system)

i have a problem to calibrate my touchscreen monitor in Ubuntu 11.10 with 2 Monitors in Dual-Screen, but only 1 touch device. I want to use only the touch monitor (Iiyama ProLite T1731SR-1) to work on it, and the extended monitor to display an Image. 
I´ve tried to conigurate the touch with the calibration Tool (egalax Touch for Kernel 3.0) but it´s shown on both monitors. So if I only use the touch to calibrate, the cursor reaches over both screens.
I think in the older version of the calibration tool for kernel 2.6 it was possible to choose, which device is the touch device. In this tool there is no possibility to choose.

Have anyone an idea, how to realize this configuration?
Thanks for your help!