# Touchscreen wrong response when connected with two monitors

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, touchscreen

I'm having an issue with my touchscreeen response which a little hard to describe. I've made this video to allow every body to see the problem I'm having here. https://youtu.be/fB6Y9trnr48

When I'm connected with only one monitor, the touchscreen of my laptop, I have a good response. But, when I connect the second monitor on HDMI port, I cannot work with it.

I checked out this question ([How do I calibrate a touchscreen on a dual monitor system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51445/how-do-i-calibrate-a-touchscreen-on-a-dual-monitor-system)) and have made this procedure (`xinput map-to-output 12 eDP-1` and `xinput map-to-output 13 eDP-1`) to align the input and output monitor in touchscreen operations.

I see that the output is aligned with my input command, but the system response is not adequate.

When I click a button, it isn't selected immediately. I need to wait a time after the command for the system select the button.

When I press in the desktop background, it works like I have a pressed mouse button.

The video in youtube can show these phenomenons better than my words.

Does anybody knows how to fix it?