# "inputattach" doesn't survive suspend / resume

Tags: suspend, 20.10, serial-port

I've been reading quite a lot on suspend / resume, in here and other internet resources, and tried countless (too many to quote here) of the hints given; in vain...

My setup requires `inputattach`, and this always had a problem with suspend / resume as it didn't come back cleanly after a resume. I never succeeded in using the "hooks" provided in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`: my scripts (built after examples in the documentation) in there were correctly(!) run during resume, but their effect was none. In `journalctl` I can see the script executed, as the `root` user, the `inputattach` process created, and its PID listed:

```
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]: echo "... in test ...  $(whoami) -- $1"
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]: ... in test ...  root -- post
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]: case $1 in
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]:   post)
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]:         { inputattach -mman /dev/ttyS0 --daemon --always & disown; echo $!; }
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]:     ;;
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]: esac
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18074]: + inputattach -mman /dev/ttyS0 --daemon --always
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]: + echo 18074
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18057]: 18074
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18075]: + ps -elfH
    Mär 04 16:48:42 RudisPC systemd-sleep[18076]: 0 S root       18074   18057  0  80   0 -  1458 do_sel 16:48 ?        00:00:00         inputattach -mman /dev/ttyS0 --daemon --always
```

but when `resume` has finished, that process is gone. Does it require special permissions / privileges to be accepted by the kernel and persist?

One observation: When running `inputattach` at boot time, or manually after `resume`, I see something like these entries in `journalctl`:

```
Mär 04 16:48:50 RudisPC kernel: serio: Serial port ttyS0
Mär 04 16:48:50 RudisPC kernel: input: Logitech M+ Mouse as /devices/pnp0/00:06/tty/ttyS0/serio7/input/input18
```

which don't show up after process creation in the `sleep`- hook.

My workaround for ages was to have an alias that, after resume had finished, ran `inputattach` again. This doesn't work any more ever since the upgrade to 20.10. This may be as (now?) the `systemctl suspend` command is asynchronous, and will not wait for the suspend/resume cycle to complete. I don't recall what it was before the upgrade.

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here? Any ideas / hints? Could there be a smart `dbus` / `udev` action doing the trick?

Comment: You might have some success using a systemd Unit as in my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620151/119298). Try the 2nd part after the dividing line: it is derived from an archlinux unit that is proven to be able to run a command at suspend, and another at resume. But the hack is to use this to stop/start *another* unit with the actual real command in it. This may help getting round systemd's habit of killing off processes when a unit ends, which is not a problem when you only run short-lived commands on resume.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create an UDEV rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. I assume that you want to attach the Logitech mouse, so find the correct rule by entering:

```
sudo udevadm monitor --environment --udev
```

Plugin the mouse and analyze the data the command above will log to the console: (Yours will look different!)

> UDEV  [43482.659634] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.6 (usb)
> ACTION=bind
> DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.6
> SUBSYSTEM=usb DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/007 DEVTYPE=usb_device
> DRIVER=usb PRODUCT=93a/2521/100 TYPE=0/0/0 BUSNUM=001 DEVNUM=007
> SEQNUM=3718 USEC_INITIALIZED=43481815203 ID_VENDOR=093a
> ID_VENDOR_ENC=093a ID_VENDOR_ID=093a ID_MODEL=USB_OPTICAL_MOUSE
> ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20OPTICAL\x20MOUSE ID_MODEL_ID=2521 ID_REVISION=0100
> ID_SERIAL=093a_USB_OPTICAL_MOUSE ID_BUS=usb ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:
> ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Pixart Imaging, Inc.
> ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Optical Mouse
> ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5.6
> ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_5_6
> ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_5_6 MAJOR=189 MINOR=6
> TAGS=:seat: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:

In this case you create a file it the folder mentioned above like `40-attach.rules` and write the following rule:

```
ACTION=="bind", ATTR{idVendor}=="093a",RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/mybashfile.sh"
```

You have to to select the ATTR values according to your data (not mine).

Basic idea is that udev will execute the command after "RUN" if it detects the hardware.

Be reminded: This is an example that is based on a device that is plugged in. You will have a different values, but it should give you the gist. You could do the same with about any hardware that is connected to your PC/Laptop

**UPDATE**

This Arch Linux [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/serial_input_device_to_kernel_input) describes how to attach a serial device to the kernel. It might help you to get around instead of using the UDEV route - which is not helpful in your case.

Another approach is listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897390/restart-touchscreen-after-resume) reawakening a touchscreen. In both cases systemd was used. Not as hook (as you tried) but as a service itself.
The most important part should be the unit definition:

```
[Unit]
 Description=restart your-inputattach service
 After=suspend.target
```

This precedes the "Service" Section, where you can define whatever your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I tried monitoring the udev events and found four `add` and one `bind`. Unfortunately, it needs `inputattach` running for the events to occur and then to start `inputattach`. Catch22! Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Yes- my solution is not useful in your case. See my updated answer.