# systemd: How to start service B after service A runs to completion?

Tags: systemd

I need to emulate the Upstart "start on stopped" behavior, in which **service B is started after service A runs to completion**, but in systemd.  How do I do that?

I've seen references to the `"After="` and `"Before="` clauses in the `[Unit]` section of the `*.service` file, but they appear to cause service B to start after service A has been **started**.  Again, I need to wait until service A has **run to completion** before starting service B.

I put together a trivial example to play with the behavior.  I put my `*.service` files in `/etc/systemd/system`, enabled the two services and then rebooted.  I expected to see `first.sh`'s "...and we're out" before `second.sh`'s "sleep for 2 seconds," but I didn't get that result, as you'll see below.

I appreciate your guidance.

====

Here are my service files, the scripts they invoke, and the journalctl output.

Here's "first.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=First of two services

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/steve/play/systemd/oneAfterTheOther/first.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's "first.sh":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
nsec=10
echo "sleep for ${nsec} seconds"
sleep ${nsec}
echo "...and we're out"
```

Here's "second.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=Second of two services
After=first.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/steve/play/systemd/oneAfterTheOther/second.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's "second.sh":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
nsec=2
echo "sleep for ${nsec} seconds"
sleep ${nsec}
echo "...and we're out"
```

And here, finally, is the journalctl output:

```
$ journalctl -u first -u second
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-09-04 17:50:19 CDT, end at Tue 2018-09-04 17:56:37 CDT
Sep 04 17:50:38 sk-xenial-vm systemd[1]: Started First of two services.
Sep 04 17:50:38 sk-xenial-vm systemd[1]: Started Second of two services.
Sep 04 17:50:40 sk-xenial-vm first.sh[900]: sleep for 10 seconds
Sep 04 17:50:40 sk-xenial-vm second.sh[924]: sleep for 2 seconds
Sep 04 17:50:43 sk-xenial-vm second.sh[924]: ...and we're out
Sep 04 17:50:51 sk-xenial-vm first.sh[900]: ...and we're out
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've come upon an answer to my own question.

I read in the [systemd.service man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) about the "`Type=`" clause, and I see that when I add "`Type=oneshot`" to the `[Service]` section of my `*.service` files, systemd does what I wanted.

I expect I could use other `Type=` settings and get results to my liking, and I also expect that I probably don't actually need to make `second.service` oneshot to get what I want; `first.service` is the one I need to see finish.  But I have a path to success now.

So, for the record, here are the working *.service files and the journalctl output to prove it.

Onward!

====

First.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=First of two services

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/steve/play/systemd/oneAfterTheOther/first.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Second.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Second of two services
After=first.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/steve/play/systemd/oneAfterTheOther/second.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Journalctl output:

```
$ journalctl -u first -u second
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-09-05 11:46:04 CDT, end at Wed 2018-09-05 11:51:54 CDT
Sep 05 11:46:21 sk-xenial-vm systemd[1]: Starting First of two services...
Sep 05 11:46:22 sk-xenial-vm first.sh[868]: sleep for 10 seconds
Sep 05 11:46:32 sk-xenial-vm first.sh[868]: ...and we're out
Sep 05 11:46:32 sk-xenial-vm systemd[1]: Started First of two services.
Sep 05 11:46:32 sk-xenial-vm systemd[1]: Starting Second of two services...
Sep 05 11:46:32 sk-xenial-vm second.sh[1104]: sleep for 2 seconds
Sep 05 11:46:34 sk-xenial-vm second.sh[1104]: ...and we're out
Sep 05 11:46:34 sk-xenial-vm systemd[1]: Started Second of two services.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the classic **double ampersand**:

```
first.sh && second.sh
```

In this example, `second.sh` will only execute, if `first.sh` was executed successfully (i.e. without errors).

Comment: Yes, I suppose. But then it wouldn't be a separate service, right?

My overarching task is to convert our current Upstart-based control to systemd. We have a number of Upstart jobs that start on completion of a predecessor job. In a few cases, one job's completion kicks off multiple successors (i.e., job A's finish launches jobs B and C).  It might be possible to crunch all of that control logic into a single job, but I sort of thought systemd would let me keep my modularity.

Thanks for the suggestion.  It might come in handy down the line.

Comment: this is a bad answer and you should remove it.  It might be okay as a quick hack but not particularly clean or scalable

Comment: @nhed I don't agree with you. I'm going to use his solution in an embedded system where I don't need scalability.